# Have Safari to validate certificate for me then redirect back to app

Tags: ios, certificate, saml, mdm

I'm currently working on an app that allows user to login with ms adfs saml. After a research I found this might not be possible to do within my app. (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1745/_index.html) I have to utilize safari for certificate authentication. The question is how exactly to accomplish the flow? I have a webview login that should open up safari to read and authenticate stored certificate. How can I have safari to redirect user back to my app and my webview will continue the work?

Comment: So what exactly do you want to do? Do you want to check some server certificate, or do you want the user to authenticate by using a digital identity?

Comment: I want user to authenticate the stored mdm certificate in safari then back to my app with enough information that I can pass to webview.

Comment: Basically, taking MS Word for example. I select login, type in my email, MS recognize that my account is managed by mdm so it opens up safari, safari then validate my stored certificate on device, back to MS Word and successfully login

Answer (score 0):

To open safari on page that can install your certificate you can use `openURL:options:completionHandler:` [method with](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1648685-openurl?language=objc) `http` or `https` scheme. When a page's installed the certificate, the page should open a url with a custom scheme.

Also you should register [custom url scheme](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app?language=objc) and open it using JS in the verification page.
Your application'll get this url in `openURL:options:completionHandler:`, in this method you can call to your webView to do next job.

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thanks for your answer. I'm not trying to install a certificate. I'm trying to have safari to authenticate the certificate. (certificate already installed on device)